# FragmentManager replace not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

When I use the replace function from FragmentManager, the fragment is being added on to the top of the stack without removing older version. All issues I'm able to find online stem from when people switch between versions of FragmentManager, but as you can see, I only use the most recent version.

```
case 2:
                            getGMCompApp().changeActivitiesFragment(new ITServiceCenterListFragment(), true);
                            break;
```

-

```
public void changeActivitiesFragment(Fragment frag, boolean addToBackStack, boolean addIfSameFragment) {
    try {
        if (frag == null) {
            // Incoming fragment is null, cancel operation
            return;
        }else if(getCurrentActivity() != null){
            //Activity is not null, attempt to change the activity

            //Grab the fragment manager
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getCurrentActivity().getFragmentManager();

            if(shouldIncomingFragmentShow(frag, addIfSameFragment)){
                //The fragment should be swapped out
                setCurrentFragment(frag);

                if(!addToBackStack){
                    //The previous fragment should NOT be added to backstack navigation
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.container, frag).commit();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Did not add to back", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // Add the current transaction to the backstack for
                    // easier navigation

                    int backStackCount = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
                    String tag = Integer.toString(backStackCount);

                    //Checks to see if fragment already exists somewhere on backStack
                    for(int i = 0; i < backStackCount; i++){
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cmp: " + frag.getClass().getSimpleName() +" with " +  fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(i).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if(frag.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(i).getName())){
                            //Fragment duplicateFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(Integer.toString(i));
                            //tag = Integer.toString(i);
                            //fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(duplicateFragment).commit();
                        }
                    }

                    fragmentManager
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.container, frag)
                            .addToBackStack(frag.getClass().getSimpleName())
                            .commit();

                }

                if(frag.getClass().equals(ViewImageFragment.class))
                {
                    getCurrentActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

                }else if(getCurrentActivity().getRequestedOrientation() != ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){

                    getCurrentActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

                }
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The relevant XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"/>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
```

I also attempted to manually remove and add the fragments, and I was not able to get remove to actually remove the fragment, which I assume is the same issue with replace (the remove part failing but the add being successful).

Thanks.

---

I created my own solution and am posting it in case it helps someone else. I manually managed the fragments and created my own stack in an array. It stores all the fragments in between the new version and old version of the duplicate fragment, and then pops off the duplicate. Restores all the in-between fragments and finally adds the brand new fragment back on top.

```
private void manageBackStack(Fragment frag){

        FragmentManager fragManager = getCurrentActivity().getFragmentManager();
        Fragment testFrag = fragManager.findFragmentByTag(frag.getClass().getSimpleName());
        if(testFrag != null) {  //If fragment already exists

            int maxIndex = fragManager.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1;
            Fragment[] stackPlaceholder = new Fragment[maxIndex];

            //Store all fragments between new fragment and its old duplicate in an array
            for (int i = maxIndex; i >= 0; i--) {
                String newFragName = fragManager.getBackStackEntryAt(i).getName();
                if(!newFragName.equals(frag.getClass().getSimpleName())) {
                    //Do not add fragments generated inside other fragments back on to the stack
                    if (!newFragName.equals("ITServiceCenterFragment")) {
                        stackPlaceholder[i - 1] = fragManager.findFragmentByTag(newFragName);
                    }
                    fragManager.popBackStackImmediate();
                }else {
                    fragManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragManager.findFragmentByTag(newFragName)).commit();
                    fragManager.popBackStackImmediate();
                    break;
                }
            }

            //Push the in-between fragments back onto the stack
            for (int i = 0; i < maxIndex; i++) {
                if (stackPlaceholder[i] != null) {
                    String fragName = stackPlaceholder[i].getClass().getSimpleName();
                    fragManager
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.container, stackPlaceholder[i], fragName)
                            .addToBackStack(fragName)
                            .commit();
                }
            }
        }

        //Push most recent fragment onto stack
        fragManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, frag, frag.getClass().getSimpleName())
                .addToBackStack(frag.getClass().getSimpleName())
                .commit();
    }
```

Comment: 1. Add logcat output to the question. 2. Where & how do you initialize `frag`? 3. try running it without the line `.addToBackStack(frag.getClass().getSimpleName())` and see if it changes anything (always start as simple as possible), and 4. you have two `replace` - which one of them is not working ?

Comment: Are you sure `addToBackStack` is set to `false` ? If not you are calling `addToBackStack`.

Comment: @alfasin is there anything specific I should post? There's no crashes so it doesn't look very relevant. Frag is initialized as a new fragment class and is then passed into the function above, I'll edit the post to include all of this. Removing addtoBackStack stops the stack from being populated by anything. The second replace is the one failing, addToBackStack boolean is only false when the original fragment is called when the application starts.

Comment: You can also try running `fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();` after the `commit`

Comment: Just tried, old versions of the fragments still exist on the stack.

Comment: You're really mixing those fragments up. If you need to extract previous fragment from the backstack and remove them and add them to the top you should do all the fragment handling manually.